# The list of coefficients of the "polynomial", which has the order of derivatives instead of degrees

Tags: programming, polynomials, coefficients, code

I have some equation

```
eqn = (A + B).x''[t] + Transpose[x'[t]].(2 A - 3 B + 1).x'[t] +(СС - 5).y'[t]+ Sin[x[t]+y[t]]
```

I need to collect all the coefficients at `x''[t],x'[t],y'[t]` and free term `Sin[x[t]+y[t]]`

That is, to get something like:

```
X = A + B
Y = Transpose[x'[t]].(2 A - 3 B + 1)
Z = CC - 5
F = Sin[x[t]+y[t]]
```

How to do it with in Mathematica automatically?

Comment: Perhaps this can be of use for the non-constant terms: ``Cases[eqn, Dot[a_, Derivative[i_][z_][t_]] :> a]``.

Comment: Or ``CoefficientList[eqn /. Dot[a_, Derivative[n_][z_][t]] :> a z^n, {x, y}]`` to get all of them. However, you have given just one example so I am not sure whether this is general enough for all your cases.

Comment: @Domen can you form your comment, as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Replace` to convert derivatives to powers, wrapped in some arbitrary head, and then use any of the existing functions to get the coefficients (e.g. `CoefficientList` or `CoefficientRules`).

```
derivativeCoefficients[eqn_] := 
 CoefficientRules[
   eqn /. (a_) . Derivative[n_][z_][t] | a_*Derivative[n_][z_][t] :> 
     a d[z]^n, {d[x], d[y]}] /. d[z_]^n_ :> Derivative[n][z][t]

eqn = (A + B) . x''[t] + 
  Transpose[x'[t]] . (2 A - 3 B + 1) . x'[t] + (CC - 5) . y'[t] + 
  Sin[x[t] + y[t]]

derivativeCoefficients[eqn]

(* {{2, 0} -> A + B, 
    {1, 0} -> Transpose[x'[t]] . (1 + 2 A - 3 B), 
    {0, 1} -> -5 + CC, 
    {0, 0} -> Sin[x[t] + y[t]]} *)

{X, Y, Z, F} = {{2,0}, {1,0}, {0,1}, {0,0}} /. %
```

This should now also work for simple multiplicative coefficients.

```
eqn = a x''[t] + 5 x'[t] - 2 y'[t] + x[t] y[t]
derivativeCoefficients[eqn]

(* {{2, 0} -> a, 
    {1, 0} -> 5, 
    {0, 1} -> -2, 
    {0, 0} -> x[t] y[t]} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And what is this replacement for numbers? Is it possible to get the coefficients in the form in which they stand for the corresponding derivatives?

Comment: @dtn, I have edited my answer to include this.

Comment: Yes, it works. I will try your approach on other equations.